# Setting autocomplete input with yii2?

Tags: html, input, autocomplete, yii2

How can I change the input width when I use an autocomplete widget in an active form. This is what I have:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')
               ->label('Imię i nazwisko')
               ->widget(AutoComplete::classname(), [
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'source' => [$data],
                     ]
               ])
  ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email')->label('Adres email') ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone')->label('Telefon') ?>
 </div>
```

The autocompleter widget works but I have a problem with the input box. As you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Xq6.png) the "Imię i nazwisko" autocomplete box is much smaller than the others. How can I select my prefer width of this input?

Comment: ->textInput(['style'=>'width:400px']) dont work

Comment: Did you try add another array with index `'options'` with element `'style'=>'width: 400px'` after `'clientOptions'` ?

Comment: of course not. It works thanks man ;))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aslawin for helping with the answer!

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')
           ->label('Imię i nazwisko')
           ->widget(AutoComplete::classname(), [
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'source' => [$data],
                ],
                'options' => ['style'=>'width: 400px']
           ])
?>
```